# How to make a Column in a Grid share the same size in Universal Windows Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

In WPF we had the Grid.SharedSizeGroup property. This made it possible to create layouts like this:

[image]

As you can see, the width of all first columns is the same, and it's determined by the wider of them.

This is the XAML (WPF).

```
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LeftColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>The</TextBlock>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Azure"></Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LeftColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>The quick</TextBlock>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="DeepSkyBlue"></Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LeftColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>The quick brown fox</TextBlock>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue"></Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LeftColumn" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</TextBlock>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkBlue"></Border>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I get the same behavior in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the same behavior in UWP?

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="AutoColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="OtherColumn"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AutoColumn}">The</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="text2" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AutoColumn}">The quick</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="text3" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AutoColumn}">The quick brown fox</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="text4" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AutoColumn}">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Background="Azure" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=OtherColumn}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=text1}"></Button>
            <Button Background="DeepSkyBlue" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=OtherColumn}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=text2}"></Button>
            <Button Background="Blue" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=OtherColumn}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=text3}"></Button>
            <Border Background="DarkBlue" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=OtherColumn}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=text4}"></Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

I am not being able to actually reproduce this using **border** instead of the **button** control (for some reason which i am not identifying right now), but the rest seems according to your desires!

[image: Result obtained with the previous XAML Code]

---

**Edit 1**
Previous solution was actually working for the Border control, despite i actually thought it wasn't (one of Stackpanel's items above is actually a border xD). Anyway, during the process i did have a lot of problems with it and it's definitely less flexible than the button for the look i was trying to force upon it.

In the code above, some of the bindings might have been unnecessary and actually setting ***VerticalAlignment*** and ***HorizontalAlignment*** to *stretch* would have produced the same result, but in general it can be really helpful in certain situations!

---

**Edit 2**

I spent more time on this, than i would probably like to admit, but still couldn't achieve your desired look. Going through the ListView Template and removing the spacing between the items will give you the desired look, even if the implementation might be actually sub-optimal.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="LISTVIEW_TEXT" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="LISTVIEW_COLOR" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Background="{Binding color}" Height="20" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LISTVIEW_COLOR}" VerticalAlignment ="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

In the code-behind i was setting the ItemsSource directly with the Colors and Text lists. [image]

Comment: That's a cool trick! but how could you make it work if each of the items is generated using a ListView with ItemsSource?

Comment: Edited my post, with an attempt of doing so.